# SCSS code not working, but bootstrap-sass does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, bootstrap-sass

Development environment: Ubuntu 16.04, rvm, rails 5, ruby 2.3.0, postgres 9.4.

Well...after since I been using bootstrap-sass for this rails project my scss code doesn't work. Whether I write it in application.scss file, or user.scss and page.scss file. I even removed the following code in my application.scss file:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

.....and still no luck.

my pages.scss has the following content:

```
myFooter
{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:3;
  width:50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I'am basically trying to style my own footer instead of relying on bootstrap presets.

I've tried using rails assets:clean && and rails assets:precompile command due to looking at other questions on stackoverflow, but nothing works.

Comment: cleared browser cache? sometimes styles get stuck if you're reloading pages a bunch

Comment: @Polyov I tried that, no luck. Thanks for the feedback though

Comment: you have `myFooter` - did you mean `.myFooter` or `#myFooter` ?